# $(this) .prop() only works the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, prop

I want to create an engine, that asks a random question (in this case, a random number). When its answered correctly,(by pressing the right button) it asks a new one.  My code only works the first time. Afther that the right button is always the one, that was pressed the first time

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1);
$('#my_div').text(number);


$('button').click(function() {
    var buttonNumber = $(this).prop('id');

    if(buttonNumber == number){
        $('#my_div2').text(buttonNumber);

        setTimeout(function(){
        var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1); 
        $('#my_div').text(number);
        }, 1);
    }
    else{ $('#my_div2').text("wrong");}
});

});
```

in case you need html

```
<html>

<div id="buttons">
        <button id="1">1</button>
        <button id="2">2</button>
        <button id="3">3</button>
        <button id="4">4</button>
        <button id="5">5</button>
</div>

<div id="my_div"> X </div>

<div id="my_div2"> X </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Why did you tag this "math"?

Comment: by mistake, and I forgot to change it. Its done now :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is where you set the new number

```
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1);  //<--- you use var
```

That will not replace the number variable declared before it. So remove the `var`

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1);
    $('#my_div').text(number);


    $('button').click(function() {
        var buttonNumber = $(this).prop('id');

        if(buttonNumber == number){
            $('#my_div2').text(buttonNumber);

            setTimeout(function(){
                number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1); 
                $('#my_div').text(number);
            }, 1);
        }
        else{ $('#my_div2').text("wrong");}
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttons">
        <button id="1">1</button>
        <button id="2">2</button>
        <button id="3">3</button>
        <button id="4">4</button>
        <button id="5">5</button>
</div>

<div id="my_div"> X </div>

<div id="my_div2"> X </div>
```

Comment: It just had to be something simple as that :D 
thank you !!